# Infinite light speed, limited-range gravity and non-dilatable time, could it be self-consistent?

Tags: physics, alternate-reality

I came up with some ideas concerning the laws of physics in a fictional universe. I changed some laws that govern our reality in order to explain and justify many phenomenons like interstellar communication and travelling while trying to make day to day life not so much different from what we experience.

My question is the following : ***Would this set of laws be self-consistent and would they make life there much different from ours?***

(Also, could they somehow be backed-up with maths someday or does it go too deep into fantasy and "magic"?)

- The universe would be static, non expanding nor collapsing and finite. It would have a central point, a specific point in space that can be calculated and mapped onto a grid. Universal and exact coordinates would exist and maybe permit the opening of magic-based portals or alien/god technology.
- Gravity would have a "limited range", the more massive is the object, the greater is its gravitational range, but at some point and at a certain distance gravity would stop operating. I thought this might explain how the universe stays static, never collapsing, while keeping some familiar physics laws. Also, i would prefer most of the star clusters and galaxies to be static, in a certain cohesion with how gravity works in this universe, of course.
- Time is universal. Gravitation does not dilate time, so wherever you are in the universe, time is the same. The big problem about that is that I have no idea how I would explain the fact that stars would still burn for billion years. Maybe somehow making gravitation dilating time only beyond a certain mass. (But I have no idea how this would/could work)
- Light and waves travel at **infinite speed**. BUT would fade as they travels. So we could observe the surrounding space instantly without delay while avoiding the effects of  Olbers' Paradox (however, I guess that wouldn't be a problem due to the small size of the universe, so I might drop that. -see clarifications-). We could also measure distances with the state of fading of the particles of light. And also communicate and receive transmissions instantly but with a certain variation in quality and clarity due to the distance.

Clarifications:

- **Goal** - This is for short stories, taking place in a world where sapient species have colonised interstellar worlds, so there would be quite a lot of moments in space. However, I'd like it to be very similar to what we would experience in our reality (at least in terms of sensorial experience), while being convenient.
- **Size** - It would be very small. About a third of size of the Local Group in which is the Milky Way. It would have a diameter of 1 mpc and host about 60 star clusters and galaxies scattered quite equally within the universe. (Even though I'd use only one star cluster/galaxy for my short stories)
- **Fading light** - About than, knowing how the universe is small, and saying a person would be at the center of the universe, there wouldn't be enough stars in the sky for the Olbers' Paradox to take place anyway, right? More so with what Michael Kjörling pointed out about "EM radiation spreading uniformly, becoming less concentrated the farther you get from the source."
- **Gravity and star formations** - The universe was created by a deity. So it kind of appeared like this a couple billion years ago, a great number of the things contained in this universe was not "naturally created".

Comment: What do you mean by "plausible"? We *know* our universe does not work that way.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange! I would recommend changing your aim from plausibility to self-consistency. Modifying the laws of physics often lead to contradictions that can doom (in any sense of the word) a universe. I'd also like to see two things clarified: Is the speed of light infinite or finite (this has implications for causality), and is a really modified and somehow consistent general relativity applicable here, or is it out the window, which seems to be the case?

Comment: Depends on your goals. Just create some space adventure? Star wars makes a lot of money and absolutelty no sense. If you want to reinvent physics and have the math work out at the end: no chance.

Comment: Light "fading or vanishing" already happens due to simple geometry. EM radiation, such as light, spreading uniformly, will become less concentrated the farther you get from the source. There's probably a gazillion drawings on the Internet that illustrate this far better than I can.

Comment: Well, our universe doesn't work the way you are describing. Since its the only universe we know, no one in this boring universe can assess whether your fictitious universe is 'plausible.' What I think you really want to do is say: this is how the laws of physics work in my universe, how would this affect X. But, be warned, that questions seems pretty broad. We don't know all the secrets of physics in our own world, its pretty hard to say for certain the far-reaching consequences of a different set of physics laws. For now, I'm voting to close this question as 'opinion based.'

Comment: @HDE226868 A universal concept of "now" would work nicely with light travelling instantaneously, but OP's light travelling "instantly, at a near infinite speed" seems self-contradictory.

Comment: @kingledion I remember from the site's early days, we'd field such questions from time to time. The answer was almost always that it broke some completely fundamental aspect and you'd have *no* universe...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I feel like the limited range of gravity and lack of expansion/contraction would prevent star formation. Even if stars did form perturbations from supernova would blast everything into a uniform density gas cloud. No universe, yay!

Comment: Anything can happen in a universe which ***you*** invent. What you're describing makes no sense in our reality, therefore it is not plausible. However, that's the way you want to write your story, and that's fine. However, at that point you're asking us for suggestions for improvement, and/or comments, which has no place on WB SE.

Comment: Time dilation has nothing important to do with why stars burn for billions of years. They do that because they have the fuel and total mass needed for gravitational fusion in their center, none of which is significantly affected by a limited range of gravity or time dilation due to gravity. To form solar systems and galaxies much like what we observe, your new gravity must extend for thousands of light years, about the width of a large galaxy.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The OP wrote: "Light (and waves) travels instantly, at a near infinite speed or at a speed multiplied by a consequent number (say a thousand) in space." This suggests what is wanted is effectively instantaneous light, but hasn't quite decided on how to achieve the effect. A thousand times *c* is probably too slow to do that. Not unless this universe was very small indeed.

Comment: @Amadeus Good points on how this fictional universe might work. If this universe is very small, much smaller than a galaxy, its short-range gravitation could hold together stars at very high densities. Greater than star clusters, for example. That would make interstellar travel much easier.

Comment: @HDE226868 Lighten up! It's the Festive Season. This is a fictional universe. It only has to be sufficiently plausible to persuade an informed layperson, not *Physical Review* plausible. This model makes good use of Olbers' Paradox & the 'tired light' hypothesis. Breaking the link between space & time would give an absolute time cosmology without causality problems.

Comment: I quite disagree that this is "primarily opinion based". All of these features can be achieved within the mathematical framework of known physics by twiddling values of the appropriate free parameters, and the follow-on consequences logically worked out. There may be more than one way to do it, with which approach is best being subject to opinion, but I see nothing wrong with that.